# How do i calculate the accuracy of an algoruthm?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-segmentation, machine-learning

I'm doing research on an machine learning image processing algorithm (segmentation algorihtm)i.e. computer vision performs when an image takes as an input and objects in an image are segmented and counted. i wanna ask how can i calculate the accuracy of my model in MATLAB. i searched many links, there's have some training taken to get the accuracy but i'm confused in it. i'm working in machine learning algorithm not deep learning. so is there some other method to find accuracy except it or not?

Comment: Typically you just generate a test corpus with known correct answers. Than apply your algorithm and compare to the known asnwers

Comment: Please let the automated spell checker of your browser run over your question; that will help you fix capitalization.